# Scala and Java mix in visual studio code

Tags: java, scala, build, editor, ensime

I have been using IntelliJ IDEA for a predominantly maven based Java project that has some Scala code as well. The pom.xml uses scala-maven-plugin with scala-compile-first working well. I tried porting this project to Visual Studio code and found that the Java code does not recognise the existence of a Scala generated classes. In effect, the Java classes when referring to Scala classes shows "Type not found error". I have used Scala extension based on Ensime for VS Code https://github.com/dragos/dragos-vscode-scala. Not sure where it is going wrong. Any pointers would help.

Comment: I do not have intention to be sarcastic or grumpy, but why are you trying to change IDE? I develop in Scala, TS and Go and reconciled to the idea of using both VS and Intellij. Yes, sometimes make mistakes using shortcuts, but I cannot abandon Intellij. It works too good with Scala (for free).